# I want to update 7 progress bars in C# list view at the same time

Tags: c#

I put the progress bar in the list view and implemented each update.
I want to run the 7 progress bars inserted in the list view at the same time using a background worker.
Help me how to do it

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new
        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I want to update the program bar of a total of 7 columns through the background worker.
The purpose is to express file copying and completion status at the same time

```cs
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int N = 7;
    ListView listview1 = null;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listview1 = listview1; }));
    ListViewItem lvi;
    ProgressBar pb;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        UpdateItemValue(i.ToString(), i);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / listView1.Items.Count, i);
    }
    e.Result = N;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items[0].SubItems[3].Text = "Done";
}

private void UpdateItemValue(string key, int value)
{
    //There is also a cross-thread problem in the UpdateItemValue method[enter image description 
    //here][1]
    ListViewItem lvi;
    ProgressBar pb;

    lvi = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.SubItems[0].Text == key);
    if (lvi != null)
        lvi.SubItems[2].Text = value.ToString();

    pb = listView1.Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == key);
    if (pb != null)
        pb.Value = value;
}
```

This method adds a column to the list view and adds a progress bar.

```cs
private void Additem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

    if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listView1.BeginUpdate();

        lvi.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
        lvi.SubItems.Add("111");

        lvi.SubItems.Add("222");
        lvi.SubItems.Add("333");
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        Rectangle r = lvi.SubItems[2].Bounds;
        pb.SetBounds(r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
        pb.Minimum = 0;
        pb.Maximum = 100;
        pb.Value = 0;
        pb.Name = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();                   // use the key as the name
        listView1.Controls.Add(pb);
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

What I want to do with this code
When you insert 7 progress bars in the list view and click the update button
At the same time, you are moving the 7 progress bars in Lisview until they reach 100%.

Comment: explain what your code is currently doing, don't leave it up to inference.  Also, it's not clear what problem you are having in your attempt to do this task.  Please explain that clearer.

Comment: This can't go anywhere as posted.  You either need to set the ListView.OwnerDraw property and paint progress yourself with ProgressBarRenderer.  Or create a UserControl with 3 labels and a ProgressBar, add them to a FlowLayoutPanel.